# Variable has feature 1, expected 127 in Machine Learning Model

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, machine-learning-model

I have created a ML model to test the password strength. The data set has a shape (669639, 127) and if I pass a password/variable to test the model, it gets a ValueError that password has 1 feature, expected 127. So, I tried to reshape the password/variable to (1,127) but it says cant reshape array of size 1 to (1,127). Any help would be highly appreciated, thank you.
`#!/usr/bin/env python

## coding: utf-8

## In[2]:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

## In[3]:

```
data = pd.read_csv('D:\Datasets\strength.csv',',', error_bad_lines=False)
```

## In[4]:

```
data
```

## In[5]:

```
data.isna().sum()
```

## In[6]:

```
data.dropna(inplace = True)
```

## In[7]:

```
data.isna().sum()
```

## In[8]:

```
sns.countplot(data['strength'])
```

## In[9]:

```
data['strength'].value_counts()
```

## In[10]:

```
password_tuple = np.array(data)
```

## In[11]:

```
import random
random.shuffle(password_tuple)
```

## In[12]:

```
X = [labels[0] for labels in password_tuple]
y = [labels[1] for labels in password_tuple]
```

## In[13]:

```
def char_tokenizer(input):
    characters = []
    for i in input:
        characters.append(i)
    return characters
```

## In[14]:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer = char_tokenizer)
X = tfidf.fit_transform(X)
```

## In[15]:

```
X.shape
```

## In[16]:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
logReg = LogisticRegression(penalty='l2',multi_class='ovr')
logReg.fit(X,y)
```

## In[17]:

```
print(logReg.score(X,y))
```

## In[18]:

```
import joblib
joblib.dump(logReg,'LogisticRegression_model.joblib')
```

## In[17]:

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
bnb = BernoulliNB()
bnb.fit(X,y)
```

## In[18]:

```
print(bnb.score(X,y))
```

## In[19]:

```
import joblib
joblib.dump(bnb,'NaiveBayes_model.joblib')
```

## In[20]:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier()
dtc.fit(X,y)
```

## In[21]:

```
print(dtc.score(X,y))
```

## In[22]:

```
import joblib
joblib.dump(logReg,'DecisionTree_model.joblib')
```

## In[23]:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
rfc = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, max_depth=50, criterion='entropy')
rfc.fit(X,y)
```

## In[24]:

```
print(rfc.score(X,y))
```

## In[25]:

```
import joblib
joblib.dump(rfc,'RandomForest_model.joblib')
```

## In[35]:

```
array =['dbswjwiqmd']
ar2 = np.array([array])
ar2.reshape(1,127)
logReg.predict(ar2)
```

`

Comment: How do you "pass a password/variable"? How to you go from the password to the 127 features of the password? It sounds like there is an error in your code, but you are not showing your code.

Comment: What function are you using? What do the docs say it expects as input?

Comment: I have added the code please have a look now.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your training dataset has 127 columns which are extracted as features. To test the password, you need the apply feature extraction methods too. From 1 string/password you need to generate a vector  with 127 columns.

Comment: Can you please share your data sample and edit your code? It is not readable.

Comment: Could you pls elaborate on how to create a vector with 127 columns from a string? is it using numpy?